# Dofollow or Nofollow trackbacks?

Tags: seo, wordpress, pagerank, comments

Thinking about SEO, is it better that they are *dofollow* trackback or *nofollow* trackbacks?

When I write a post on my blog, I automatically send trackback to my site from http://bitacoras.com. The above link is dofollow. Is it advisable to give relevance to this link in also handling dofollow link?

For example any domain on the homepage has pagerank 3. This site has a pagerank 0 of the  internal page that I send trackbacks to. Is it convenient to send dofollow links to that page to increase the pagerank? Will they increase my pagerank if I perform this operation?

Comment: There really isn't such a thing as a dofollow link: adding `rel=dofollow` to links wont mean that anyone crawler will be forced to visit that page.

Comment: I do not want to force to visit the page.Thought to increase the PageRank of the page that sends the link .Then these links in turn would increase my pagerank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a best title for this question would be:

**Do Trackbacks and Pingbacks matter when it comes to SEO**?

By sending a trackback, you are creating a backlink to your blog, which takes a very small amount of time to do when considering the benefits of it.

> “A trackback is a super comment. The way that a trackback works, is instead of a going to a blog and posting a comment on someone else’s blog, you post a reply on your own website and post a trackback comment. Unless they don’t allow follows, but you still establish authority” - [Mattew Bredel](http://www.matthewbredel.com/)

For your purposes of building blogger to blogger relationships, trackbacks and pingbacks are both great ways to establish a site’s presence inside a blog community, and as a bonus, you are inadvertently getting backlinks that will only help you (if they are of quality and not from red flagged sites).

#### My personal opinion:

I see trackback more as a way of establishing blogger to blogger relationship rather than building backlinks. After all, it just another way of reciprocal link.

Comment: The concept of trackbacks know him. Thank you for your personal opinion. I sincerely hope some good opinion in any authoritative source, about the question.

Answer (score 3):

Ernesto there is no link type of `dofollow`, and `nofollow` is not really a w3 standard. Search engines have agreed to recognize it as a link not to count towards your search positions. It doesn't mean they won't crawl and index it though.

If you want to increase your page rank any good quality standard href link on a relevant page linking to your page will help with enough links. The page linking to you should be at the least cached by Google and the higher the PR of the page linking to you the better. Your links should be above the fold and contextual when possible.

If a link does not contain `rel="nofollow" then by default Google and others will count it towards your overall incoming links.

According to w3 standards though when there are two duplicate attributes in an `a` tag the first one takes precedence. So it may be possible that if a link forces `rel="nofollow"` and you are able to add any other `rel=""` attribute before it in the source that it may override the nofollow. That's an assumption and I don't know how Google would treat that.

Comment: My bad English has prevented you understand what I'm asking. My comments trackbacks are default nofollow. And as I have understood not serve to increase pagerank. I'm thinking in  increase pagerank page, for other page. (Not mine) Then the links would send me have more pagerank.

Comment: I'd let all trackbacks be follow so remove nofollow from trackbacks to help get some backlinks.

Comment: I 'm not thinking ( not want ) in trackback spam links .That is another issue.

Comment: Then disable trackbacks entirely.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, I want to criteria recognized sources. Even I am sure that is not similar dofollow link to a nofollow link.